# Why do UX guidelines discourage commands for tree items?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The [UX guidelines](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/views#tree-views) for tree views discourage use of commands. However, the `TreeItem` API has a property for adding a command. Why discourage it if it's part of the API?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [ux.se]

Comment: It is confusing.  I wonder if it is just about visibility, after all you could fire any command in a selection listener.  Outside of a tooltip the user would not know that an action is about to be triggered.  If the actions are put into a context menu the user can see that information and opt out easily if desired.

Comment: See also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149254 - that issue is about how to make tree items look like buttons if there is a command attached.  I suppose to make it look obvious to the user that it is actually a button.  There isn't any mention in that issue that tree items as buttons is a bad thing.

Answer (score -1):

Please read carefully. It says you should not use a tree item **as a button** to trigger commands. It's certainly fine to trigger something on selection, like scrolling something into view, which belongs to that item.

The term **as a button** could mean that nothing visually unrelated to the tree item should be triggered.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a little more sense, but "as a button" alone does not convey that notion. The guidelines need more context like what you described. To "trigger something on selection" is exactly what a button does, so the quality of my reading is irrelevant.

Comment: @david-fong I suppose I can open an issue but not a PR. I don’t know what they intended, hence this question, so I wouldn’t know what to put in the changes.